# Sql Statement cutting Rows in half

Tags: mysql, select, into-outfile

Here is my current sql query

```
        SELECT 
    w.city, t.tmc, t.date, t.time, w.event, 
    ROUND(AVG(w.Pave), 0) surface_temperature, 
    ROUND(AVG(w.Air), 0) air_temperature, 
    ROUND(AVG(a.material_rate),0) material_rate, 
    w.intensity, t.avg 
    FROM winter2010.traffictest t 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN winter2010.application a ON a.DATE = t.DATE AND a.tmc = t.tmc AND a.tmc = t.tmc AND Left(a.time,2) = Left(t.time, 2) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN winter2010.weather w ON t.DATE = w.DATE AND t.tmc = w.tmc AND  Left(t.time, 2) =  Left(w.time, 2) 
    GROUP BY tmc, t.time 
    INTO OUTFILE 'c:/sass2.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES 
TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I'm creating this csv file from the following sql statement and it works great except for one thing, its only taking 1/2 the rows!

There are a total of 2661 rows in traffictest
And when I outfile the data into the csv its only putting 1331.

I've changed the size of traffictest and this holds true except when I had only 3 rows it actually pulled all three rows.

Any help figuring this out would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would guess the problem is in `GROUP BY tmc, t.time`; too many rows are grouped together. How many rows do you get if you drop the group by? Maybe you should replace this clause with `group by t.primary_key_of_t`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `GROUP BY` MySql returns only one row per group, You have rows with similar tmc-time and MySql is returning only one row for all such rows that's the reason for decrease in row number.